# Extracting items out of a QueryDict

Tags: python, django

I have a querydict that looks like the following:

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"content":"aa","id":"1"}': [u'']}>
```

How would I extract out `id`?

I have tried doing `queryDictExample.get("id")`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Fix the client-side app that's resulting in the broken object first.

Comment: How can I re-create your variable? I'm not familiar with hits syntax.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It seems like your client is posting JSON rather than formencoded data. Instead of accessing `request.POST`, use `request.body` (`request.raw_post_data` in versions 1.3 or less) and use `json.loads()` to convert to a dict.

Comment: or just add `content_type='application/json'` on your client

Comment: Well you could do that, but it wouldn't solve OP's problem in any way at all.

Comment: QueryDict is not limited to a  request.POST only as it may also be seen on request.GET. Maybe you can share how to use a proper `queryDictExample.get("id") `?

Comment: so you would basically do `json.loads(request.body)`?. I got a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: import json
data = json.loads(request.body )
data.get("key")

Answer (score 12):

Maybe this doesn't fully apply to you. But when I searched for this, your question was the first Stackoverflow question.

I just wanted to get basic POST data out in Django. So just using GET worked fine for me. As the others stated, it might be easier to better format whatever script is creating the query.

Basically I have a AJAX doing a post towards Django, the POST looks a bit like this:

```
params = name=somename&data=abcdefg
http.send(params);
```

then in my view.py, i did this :

```
def somefuntion(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        log.info('POST applied')
        alldata=request.POST
        log.debug(alldata)
        data = alldata.get("data", "0")
        name = alldata.get("name", "0")
        log.info("POST name: " + name)
        log.info("POST data: " + data)
```

The output of alldata was :

```
<QueryDict: {u'data': [u'abcdefg'], u'name': [u'somename']}>
```

and the get commands give :

```
name: somename
data: abcdefg
```

Answer (score 9):

This works for multiple values:

```
dict(MyDict.lists())
```

Dict keys are query vars, and dict values are lists of query values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use - `request.data.get("content")` This will give you the data directly if in front end (jQuery,Angular) you have NOT used `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Answer (score 3):

Encountered similar case recently where data from POST call was in `QueryDict` form,
I was able to access value of particular key using

```
qdict.get(keyname)
```

Also I was able to iterate using `QueryDict.items()` to get tuple of key & value

```
for q in qdict.items():
    print(q)
```

Note that `QueryDict` is subclass of `Dictionary` so all standard methods of `Dictionary` can also be implemented on `QueryDict`.

More information available on djangoproject documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Answer (score 0):

this one works also for values that are lists:

```
dict_ = {k: qdict.getlist(k) if len(qdict.getlist(k))>1 else v for k, v in qdict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem. It happened when I was trying to have my request data be held in request.POST instead of request.body. I was using Django with a trusted backend route already configured to work with request.POST

In order to send the data within request.POST with the fetch API I had to use 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' which turned my JSON stringifed data into a format like above.

In learning how to serialize data from Daniel's answer I came across $.param(data), a jquery function which should format it correctly for you.

Answer (score -2):

You can use values_list on query dict, i.e.:
`MyDict.values_list('id')` - it will return list of lists with id inside. To return list of id use MyDict.values_list('id', flat=True)

Useful links:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#values

Comment: OP is talking about QueryDicts, not QuerySets.