# How to get the values of a request in Python?

Tags: python, django

I get this result when I print the `request`, which arrived at a POST.

```
<QueryDict: {u'form_values': [u'nombre=Juan&apellidos=Perez&correo=juan@email.com&confiCorreo=juan@email.com&telefono=5598764&celular=8971265256&calle_numero=Calle+#10&colonia=San+Pablo&municipio=&estado=&pais=&cPostal=&razonS=&rfc=&callenumero=&colonia=&municipio=&estado=&codPos='], u'pass': [u'k7iwriilqm66mtnu2m1x'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'kkxdVbDzPXhfDazzSVvIvAYizExoRSFR'], u'clabe': [u'8jO9ChGsKXJfrBtb4vBMsxQKdA8L7Y0h']}>
```

How can I get the values ​​that come from `form_values` individually (`nombre`, `apellidos`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are receiving a URL encoded query string, **within** the `form_values` URL parameter. If this is intended, you can parse that query string with the `urlparse` standard library like so:

```
import urlparse
url_str = query_dict["form_values"][0]
form_dict = urlparse.parse_qs(url_str)
print(form_dict)
# {'correo': ['juan@email.com'], 'calle_numero': ['Calle #10'], 'colonia': ['San Pablo'], 'confiCorreo': ['juan@email.com'], 'apellidos': ['Perez'], 'celular': ['8971265256'], 'nombre': ['Juan'], 'telefono': ['5598764']}
```

`urlparse.parse_qs` takes a query string and returns a native dictionary with a mapping of keys to list values. If a key appears more than once in the query string, the list will contain multiple values. Please refer to the [docs for more details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
d = dict(queryDict.iterlists())
formvalues = d['form_values']
queries = formvalues.split('&')
nombre = queries[0].split('=')[1]
apellidos = queries[1].split('=')[1]
```

You could also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10023515/7085732)